# Display a div when a user clicks using a javascript function

Tags: javascript, xhtml, html

I need to display on a webpage a div when a user clicks on a button.
 Does someone know how to do it ?

My code so far :

```
<body onload ="init()">
      <input type="button" value="Display the div tree" onclick="check();" />

      <script ="text/javascript">

      function check() {
      // I'd like to display on the page the div tree
      }

     </script>

      <div id = "tree" style="display:none"> // I don't want to display it unless the user clicks on the button "Display the div tree"
      </div>      

</body>
```

thanks,

Bruno

Comment: <script ="text/javascript"> => <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('tree').style.display='';
```

Include this in your check function

Comment: @Bruno -just try placing your script on the top of your page surrounded by `<head>`

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if i understood the question, this seems a bit too easy:

```
function check() {
  document.getElementById('tree').style.display=''; // or display='block';
}
```

**EDIT :**
the reason this dooesn't work *for you* is an error in your code. please change this line:

```
<script ="text/javascript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and everything wiill be fine. also, you should place the script in the `head` of your document, but thats not absolutely neccessary.

Comment: do you have a content in between your `div` that will tell you that it's displayed instead of just being `<div id="tree" style="display:none"></div>`?